# Regex не воспринимает круглые скобки в квадратных

Tags: c#, .net, регулярные-выражения

Элементарный пример кода:

```
var text = "пришли не званы, уйдем не драны";
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"[(зв)(др)]аны");
    Match match = regex.Match(text);
    while (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
        match = match.NextMatch();
    }
```

Я ожидаю увидеть в выводе "званы" и "драны", но почему-то там только "ваны" и "раны". То есть, работает так, будто никаких скобок нет. Почему так - непонятно, до этого уже писал регулярки и все было отлично. Внезапно столкнулся, когда не заработал более сложный пример и разбор ошибок привел вот к этой странной проблеме.

Comment: а так `(зв|др)аны` ?

Comment: Так всё отрабатывает. Но мой пример вроде как тоже должен работать.

Comment: потому что в квадратных скобках все посимвольно и скобки теряют свой смысл. И матчится будут также "заны", "даны", "(аны", ")аны".

Comment: А разве круглые скобки не должны образовывать группу символов? Или у квадратных в данном случае более высокий приоритет?

Comment: в квадратных скобках круглые теряют смысл

Comment: Спасибо! Вопрос снят.

Comment: @splash58: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD, да как-то писать непонятно что, кроме самого регекса, а на английском на такие ответы ругаются :)

Comment: @splash58 Ну добавьте предолжение, которое KoVadim написал, плюс ссылку на доку какую-нибудь -- уже пара-тройка предложений будет. [Как поступать с простыми вопросами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4578/213987): работа по сбору комментариев в ответ тоже полезна.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Взгляните на онлайн-тест регулярного выражения [`[(зв)(др)]аны`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%28%D0%B7%D0%B2%29%28%D0%B4%D1%80%29%5D%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B&i=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%2C%20%D1%83%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%0D%0A%28%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%29%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B&o=i):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дело в том, что пара неэкранированных квадратных скобок задаёт **символьный класс**, который находит только *один* символ из указанных символов в классе. Внутри такого класса *большинство* специальных метасимволов регулярных выражений теряют своё особое значение, превращаясь в обычный, буквальный символ. Например, часто используемые `(`, `)`, `|`, а также квантификаторы `+`, `?`, `*` и "якоря" ("привязки") `^` и `$` внутри символьного класса находят соответствующие буквальные символы.

Всегда экранировать нужно только символ `\`, символ `^` нужно экранировать только в начале *позитивного* ("включающего") символьного класса (иначе получится "исключающий" символьный класс), символ `]` нужно экранировать только если он не в самом начале символьного класса, а `-` не нужно экранировать в начале, конце и между диапазоном символов/предопределенным набором символов и другим символом.

Вам же необходим **группирующий конструкт**, т.н. (не)захватываемая подмаска (или группа), внутри которого можно задать 1 и более *альтернативных ветвей* с помощью оператора `|`.

```
(зв|др)аны
(?:зв|др)аны
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%D0%B7%D0%B2%7C%D0%B4%D1%80%29%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B&i=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%2C%20%D1%83%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%0D%0A%28%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%29%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B&o=i)

В случае с `(зв|др)` подмаска захватываемая, т.е. если совпадение будет найдено, можно посмотреть в `match.Groups[1].Value`, что же нашлось, `зв` или `др`.  Напротив, при использовании незахватывающей подмаски `(?:зв|др)` такой возможности не будет, `match.Groups[1]` будет *null*.

Кратко обо всём этом можно почитать [тут](http://mech.math.msu.su/~shvetz/54/inf/perl-problems/chRE_sSearchTemplates.xhtml) и, конечно, в Википедии, [Регулярные выражения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).